# How to write down these three cases in a more elegant way?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, conditional-statements

Is it possible to make this code more compact? Am I missing anything here?

```rb
    if value < min_rate
      min_rate
    elsif value > max_rate
      max_rate
    else
      value
    end
```

Comment: This tells the reader exactly what happens and how it happens. I'd prefer this way.

Comment: Stack Exchange's ["codereview"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1) site is the new hotness for this sort of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something completely different:

```
[min_rate, value, max_rate].sort[1]
```

Comment: Looks simple to me, or do you mean computationally expensive? Sorting a 3-element array which will likely be already sorted or at worst requires one swap is not going to be a significant performance issue in a typical use case. Unless you are doing this in a big loop.

Comment: Yes, it's a part of a big loop, so computions can become a problem

Comment: In my benchmark, it takes a loop size of 2000000 before it makes a difference of one second.

Comment: You're right, I changed my mind. I'm satisfied with `[0, partner_rate, max_rate].sort[1]`. Thank you :)

Comment: With ActiveSupport it becomes even better: `[0, partner_rate, max_rate].sort.second`

Comment: Nice! I forgot about the ordinals.

Comment: If I encountered this in real code, I would find the author and slap him for excessive cleverness, then refactor it. The cognitive load of understanding what this snippet does (figuring out how the sort interacts with various possibilities and convincing oneself that the middle value will be the original value or the appropriate bound) is way too high for the inherent complexity of the decision. If it was factored into a well-named small method it might be acceptable, but as a simple guard computation in the middle of a loop it is smelly. It is, however a clever bit of code golf.

Comment: @dbenhur I wouldn't have reached for this solution automatically when coding, but I thought it was in the spirit of the OP's question. And a well-named, small method is a must :)

Comment: @MarkThomas fair enough. It certainly answers the "compact" part of the question. To me, elegance is code which concisely _and_ clearly expresses intent while executing efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

For me this looks more readable and easily understandable. Hope you like it.

```
def some_method    
  return min_rate if value < min_rate
  return max_rate if value > max_rate

  value
end
```

Comment: It's also a great way of solving this problem, but it badly explains what's happening in code

Comment: @NickShebanov I don't think so it badly explains the code. If there are lots of iffing in your code then you have to divide your code into small methods and make each method for condition checking. Iffing adds more complexity in the code and becomes not easily readable and understandable.

Answer (score 2):

`max(min(value, max_rate), min_rate)`.  This hides the if-branching ("iffing"?) inside `min` and `max`, respectively.

Comment: This looks good, but there is no max/min methods in global scope by default.

Comment: Yes I agree with @NickShebanov, there is no max/min methods in global scope. But if you want you can do something like [[value, max_rate].min, min_rate].max, but from this you can not differ which value is greater or lesser than to other value.

Comment: The option with array solves only the code size problem, but brings complexity (both in calculations, and in readability) to the code, so this is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary assignment is "more compact", but definitely not prettier:

```
value = (value < min_rate) ? min_rate : (value > max_rate) ? max_rate : value
```

Comment: Yes, prettiness is important. Ternary operator is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Ruby allows ternary expressions to be spread across multiple lines, by putting the `?` and `:` at the end of the lines: `value = (value < min_rate) ?\n min_rate :\n (value > max_rate) ?\n max_rate :\n value`. Copy that into an editor and replace the `\n` with new-lines for the full effect. In Perl we'd use some pretty complex ternary, but with the appropriate indentation it was very readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is called Nested Ternary Operators

```
value < min_rate ? min_rate :
value > max_rate ? max_rate :
value
```

that will do
you can put everything in one line if you want, it's just for readability purpouses that it did it that way

Answer (score 0):

Well, i agree with @pwned, but there is a more elgant way of doing. IMHO Is the same thing, but with a better reading.

```
  def calculate(value)
    return min_rate if value < min_rate
    return max_rate if value > max_rate
    value
  end
```

I dont like that cascade style at all. =)

Comment: I don't like the cascade style, either, unless if is used as an expressive ternary operator to return a value which is what happens in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You might try extending Range with a utility method:

```
module RangeHelper
  def bound value
    value < self.begin ? self.begin :
    value > self.end   ? self.end :
    value
  end
end
Range.class_eval { include RangeHelper }

(1..10).bound 5  # => 5
(1..10).bound -5 # => 1
(1..10).bound 15 # => 10
```

Comment: Does anyone besides me find it annoying that this std ruby class has methods whose names clash with keywords?

Comment: I am content with using "first" and "last" which doesn't clash with keywords.

Comment: @pwned Since `first` and `last` accept an N argument, I had assumed they were not quite equivalent and potentially much less efficient as they would be implemented over `Range#each`.  Checking the source now, I see that for the argument-less invocation they are essentially equivalent to `#begin` and `#end`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Range
  def limit(value)
    if value> last
      last
    elsif value< first
      first
    else
      value
    end
  end
end

p (-50..50).map{ |n| (10..20).limit(n) }.uniq== (10..20).to_a
```

> $ true

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby 2.4 (Dec. 2016) we have a method that does this exact thing: [`Comparable#clamp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp):

```
value = 15
value.clamp(10, 20) # => 15
value.clamp(0, 10) # => 10
value.clamp(20, 30) # => 20
```

Since it's part of Comparable, it works with any class that includes Comparable, e.g.:

```
"foo".clamp("bar", "baz") # => "baz"
```